# Head First java example , Code Magnet exercise , chapter 3

Tags: java

Although the author keeps telling me to ignore what I can't understand for now , I really can't, so please explain what exactly "Ref" is doing:

```
class TestArrays {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        int [] index = new int[4];
        index[0] = 1;
        index[1] = 3;
        index[2] = 0;
        index[3] = 2;
        String [] islands = new String[4];
        islands[0] = “Bermuda”;
        islands[1] = “Fiji”;
        islands[2] = “Azores”;
        islands[3] = “Cozumel”;
        int y = 0;
        int ref;
        while (y < 4) {
            ref = index[y];
            System.out.print(“island = “);
            System.out.println(islands[ref]);
            y = y + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

**Output :**

```
island = Fiji  
island = Cozumel  
island = Bermuda  
island = Azores
```

Comment: What if you added a `System.out.print("ref = " + ref);`? That might clarify it. Are you familiar with arrays?

Comment: if you pay close attention to index array, you can see that it just performs a permutation of indexes (0,1,2,3). So index[y] actually returns an index that the author calls "ref" (short for reference). He then prints the island in island[ref]

Comment: yes i'm familiar with arrays , and thus , it wasn't clear why it has  to be that way ? why she used two arrays at that simple app ?, But thanks really for your respond ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ref doesn't do anything as it doesn't occur in the program :)  Java is case-sensitive!  ref is used to temporarily store an element from array index, which is then used to reference an element from array islands.  It's an application of a technique called a "lookup table".

so, when y = 0,

```
ref = index[y]
```

gets the 0'th element from index, which is 1.  This means that

```
islands[ref]
```

becomes

```
islands[1]
```

and thus, fetches "Fiji" from the islands array.

Comment: thanks for your respond ,  that point is clear now , But , was it necessary to use two arrays  in that app?

Comment: As they wanted to show the mapping, yes.  Without the `index` array it would be much harder to show the contents of array `islands` in a order other than its natural order.  I am not familiar with the text book you referred to, but maybe they want to build on that example later on.

Answer (score 1):

ref is actually being used as the parameter to the array island which is taking the output of array "index" and providing input to array "islands"

Iterations in while loop are as follows

```
y=0 ref=1  islands[1]=Fiji
y=1 ref=3  islands[3]=Cozumel
y=2 ref=0  islands[0]=Bermuda
y=3 ref=2  islands[2]=Azores
```

As you can see the order of output is different from the order of the index array which is why ref is used.

Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

ref is just like a pointer, in this case, the ref switched the object it pointing to and print them to the screen in the loop